# How Can I Maintain User-Specified Column Widths in a JTable?

Tags: java, jtable

So I'm working with a `JTable`, which is tied to a custom data model of my own. That much is all functional, but the problem I'm having is that any time that I make a change to the table (firing tableDataChanged, tableStructureChanged, etc.) all of the column widths reset themselves to the default values. I understand from researching that this has to do with the `TableColumnModel` assigned by default. Outside of this resetting, I'm happy with the functionality of the `DefaultTableColumnModel`, but I would just like to retain the width of the columns if a user should resize them (by dragging the edge of the column header).

I'm aware of `setPreferredWidth()` for the TableColumns, and I've been able to do that successfully; I suppose my question is what sort of event I should listen for to save and set this preferred width. I tried adding a `PropertyChangeListener` to the table header, but I would get a StackOverflow any time I tried to resize (I'm assuming it was running recursively). I'm perfectly okay with adding an additional data member in the data model for the column widths, and storing it there, but I just don't know when/how to set these widths so that they aren't overridden by the `fireTableStructureChanged()`, etc. events. Thoughts?

Comment: Before you close your process, read the column widths and save them to a properties file.  When you open your process, read the properties file and, if it exists, set the column widths.  You may need to extend the DefaultTableColumnModel so that you can control the column widths.

Comment: It actually does this at any call to fireTableStructureChanged(), not just at the start of the program, so if I add or remove columns in the data model (where it has to regenerate columns) it does this. I've tried overriding `fireTableStructureChanged()` to manually set the column widths, but it seemingly has no effect. I guess I'm just not sure exactly where this column generation is occuring and where to override it.

Comment: I've always done data driven column widths.  If I find anything, I'll provide an answer.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. Yeah, I'm new to JTables so I'm learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class ColumnResizer {

    public static void setColumnPreferredWidth(JTable table, int column,
            int preferredWidth) {
        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn tableColumn = columnModel.getColumn(column);
        tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(preferredWidth);
    }

}
```

Comment: I like the idea, and it does work, but only until the next structure change event. It got me on the right track, though, and I've realized now that it all occurs in the `addColumn()` method of the `TableColumnModel`. I located the source here: http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableColumnModel-source.html and am overriding to add a `column.setPreferredWidth()` in there as well. I'll tie a reference into my data model so it can get and set column widths as needed, and just handle it there. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What about

`table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);`

I had this problem as well, this worked for me!